# О двойственном числе в русском

Tags: грамматика, старая-грамматика

Тут возникла интересная полемика (если её так можно назвать) по поводу т.н. "двойственного числа" в русском. 
Хотелось бы знать, насколько это понятие актуально среди носителей.

1. Можете ли вы по сохранившимся в современном языке формам (рефлексам, рудиментам и фразеологизмам) легко восстановить хотя бы частично падежные формы двойственного?
2. Знаете ли местоимения двойственного числа? Можете ли проспрягать какой-нибудь глагол?
3. Можно ли говорить о "современной орфографии" этого двойственного числа - и если да, то что это такое?

Comment: Не знал о таком термине, пока не увидел этот вопрос. Видимо очень узкая тема для лингвистов.

Comment: Да, спасибо, это требует некоторой подготовки. Но не такая уж и узкая. Люди, хоть сколько-нибудь связанные с филологией, наверняка знают и  поймут о чем речь.

Comment: Носители - это кто?  Я говорю по-русски, но не только, а иногда и не столько, я - носитель?  Или вы специалистов-лингвистов только причисляете к ним?  Местоимение двойственного числа - оба, обе.  Кроме этого, пожалуй, мне про двойственное число ничего не известно.

Comment: Носители это люди, которым не надо объяснять термин "носители". Почему Вы отвечаете в комментариях?

Comment: Отвечаю?  Нет, я просто уточняю или даже спрашиваю...

Answer (score 1):

Двойственное число в современном русском языке не существует, но в языке остались его "остатки". Это, например, слова, оканчивающиеся на ударную "-а": глаза, рукава, берега, рога, бока, и т.д.

Альфред грибер пишет:

"Форма слова «уши» не объяснима от формы слова «ухо». Поэтому С. П. Обнорский предполагал форму именительного падежа единственного числа – «ушь». В этом случае слово «уши» является формой именительного падежа двойственного числа.

Остатком двойственного числа в русском языке выступает и наречие «воочию», которое является по происхождению формой местного падежа двойственного числа от слова «око» с предлогом «въ».

«Окаменевшей» формой двойственного числа является современный предлог «между». По происхождению это местный падеж двойственного числа от существительного «межда» (старославянское соответствие восточнославянскому «межа»)."
источник: http://alfred-griber.com/proizvedeniya/stati-o-yazyke-i-literature/dvojstvennoe-chislo-v-russkom-yazyke